# How to get all records from set in aerospike?

Tags: java, database, aerospike

How to get all records from set in aerospike?
And how to get bin with necessary value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get all records belonging to a set, you can use `scan` API and pass the required set. To get all records with a specific bin value, you can use secondary index. Please Refer to the [doc](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#scanAll(com.aerospike.client.policy.ScanPolicy,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.aerospike.client.ScanCallback,%20java.lang.String...)) for details.

Comment: please provide a link to the relevant documentation instead of stating "refer to the doc for details"